# theoretical Question about multithreading (scaling)

Tags: multithreading, scaling

I need to answer following question:

A server needs to do 15 ms of work per request for a file. if the file is not in cache, the harddisk must be accessed and thread sleeps for 75 ms. This happens in 1/3 of the cases.

a) How many request can the server process per second with 1 Thread?
->15 ms + 1/3 * 75 ms = 40 ms per request -> 1000/40 ms = 25 Request per second

b) How many with multiple threads?

Is there a formula for this?
For 2 threads I got 40.625 Request per second:
25 ms pause on average -> 25/40 = 0.625 -> 25 * 1.625 = 40.625 Requests per second

What about 3 or more threads?

Comment: Homework? If so, homework questions are fine on this site, but you must show you are doing some of the work.  What parts of the question are you having trouble with?

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?

Comment: There's nothing about the hard disk having to deal with requests serially, so we can assume it can go arbitarily fast. So the max through put is when all the processor time is used up doing the 15 ms of work.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm doing your homework but it is interesting because the problem statement is flawed.  It can't be answered as-is because a important piece of info is missing: the number of cores that the machine has available.  Running more threads than you've got cores doesn't improve throughput.  Assuming J jobs, T threads and C cores, the amount of time spent on them is

> time = J x 15 msec / min(T, C) + J x 75 msec / 3

Solving for J per second:

> rate = 1000 / (15 / min(T, C) + 25)